# how can i use windbg with visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windbg

i am using visual studio 2015. i want a debugger that can support scripting, for example when hit the first break point 1 it can set another break point according to the value of a local variable.

can it be done with visual studio debugger?

and i am trying to use Microsoft windows debugger with visual studio 2015. According to Microsoft's document, visual studio has support Microsoft windows debugger from visual studio 2012.

Then i choose DEBUG -> Attach to process, but no "windows user mode debugger" transport ?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: not yet, sadly :(